# Temp ArrayList to Master ArrayList with boolean &&

Tags: processing

I'm looking to iterate through three lists(all the same length), get the values at the specified index, and compare them to a master list. And for the values that are not already in the master list, append the new values.

However, my boolean and statement never goes through.

```
 FloatList master_X = new FloatList();
 FloatList master_Y = new FloatList();
 FloatList master_Z = new FloatList();

 FloatList t_x = new FloatList();
 FloatList t_y = new FloatList();
 FloatList t_z = new FloatList();

 FloatList checkedX = new FloatList();
 FloatList checkedY = new FloatList();
 FloatList checkedZ = new FloatList();


void tempToMaster(){

 for(int i = 0; i < t_x.size();i++){
  float x_t = (float)t_x.get(i);
  float y_t = (float)t_y.get(i);
  float z_t = (float)t_z.get(i);

  for(int j = 0; j < master_X.size();j++){
   float x_s = (float)master_X.get(j);
   float y_s = (float)master_Y.get(j);
   float z_s = (float)master_Z.get(j);

   if ((x_t != x_s)&&(y_t != y_s)&&(z_t != z_s)){
     print("helloWorld");
     checkedX.append(x_t);
     checkedY.append(y_t);
     checkedZ.append(z_t);
   }
  }
 }

 for(int i = 0; i < checkedX.size();i++){
  master_X.append(checkedX.get(i));
  master_Y.append(checkedY.get(i));
  master_Z.append(checkedZ.get(i));
 }

 checkedX.clear();
 checkedY.clear();
 checkedZ.clear();

 t_x.clear();
 t_y.clear();
 t_z.clear();


}
```

should Print "Hello World" as well as append the values from the temp ArrayLists to the "checked" ArrayLists.

Boolean opperation never works.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code and it works, but you have to make sure the lists aren't empty.
This is because, when masterX is empty, masterX.size() is 0.

Therefore, the for loop doesn't even start, because 0 is not smaller than 0, and nothing gets added to the checked lists.

This code:

```
  master_X.append(0);
  master_Y.append(0);
  master_Z.append(0);

  t_x.append(1);
  t_y.append(1);
  t_z.append(1);

  tempToMaster();
```

gives the expected result.

If you want it to work with empty master lists, first adding all temp lists to the checked lists and then removing all floats that are in a master list should work.

Edit: you also may want to look into [hasValue()](https://processing.org/reference/FloatList_hasValue_.html) to check if a list contains a specific float.

Comment: The funny thing is that in the actual program, neither the master list nor the temp list are empty. The above example is a method within a class that has the masters and temp lists as attributes, and I innitialize the master with 0,0,0 and add six values to the templist. This function is meant to check for overlap of position and I can't figure it out for the life of me. Thanks for you input!

Comment: That is weird indeed. Can you confirm that using your example code and adding my code in setup() yields the expected result? If so, your problem is probably somewhere else.
In that case, make sure the lists (temp lists) actually hold the values you expect them to (by printing them).